# How to create a alias in fish shell

Tags: fish

I try to create an alias for ls (should basically just map to `ls -lah`)
I've tried the following code, but it's not working:

`function ls`

`ls -lah`

`end`

`funcsave ls`

but when I call it I get this message:

> The function 'ls' calls itself immediately, which would result in an infinite loop.
> in function 'ls'
> called on standard input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to make alias of `ls`, then the above answers are OK.
However, fish already has a command for `ls -lah`, which is `la`.

Comment: Nice! Thank you, I didn't know that! :)

Comment: @ners10100100 If you want to check all fish specific commands, you can `fish_config` in terminal, which will start web config and under functions tab you'll find a lot of info about.

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is the [`command`](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#command) command.

I would also recommend to pass any arguments (stored in `$argv`) to the aliased command.

So your example should be:

```
function ls
  command ls -lah $argv
end
```

And to do all this with a simple command, you can simply use the [`alias`](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#alias) command.

```
alias ls "command ls -lah"
```

Note that usually aliases will not get you the nice auto-complete suggestions that contribute to _fish_'s friendliness. This specific case is an exception because the function and the original command have the same way, but otherwise, here are two ways to get completions anyway:

- You can use the [`complete`](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#complete) command to tell *fish* that your alias uses the same completions as the aliased command.
  The [`balias`](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/plugin-balias) plugin
  serves as an alternative to `alias` and does just that.
- *fish* also offers an [`abbr`](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#abbr) command. It works slightly different and will actually expand the abbreviated command to the full command in the command line, and then *fish* will have no problem giving you all the auto-completion suggestions that it knows.

Comment: Thank you very much! The alias/function works now! Do you have any Idea why the "colorization" of the output from `ls -lah` is gone when it's called through the function?

Comment: My guess is that your `ls` command is already wrapped by another function. I personally use `grc` so I can see exactly the same effect.
First, in a `fish` shell without your alias, run `functions ls` and see if there is some function with that name. If there is, you can rename it like this: `functions -c ls ls_color` and then in your alias function, instead of `command ls $argv`, call `ls-color $argv`.

Comment: Isn't your `ls` function missing the `command` command?

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to `abbr`. That thing is awesome!

Answer (score 3):

You need the `command` keyword. Also, pass the function's arguments to `ls`

```
function ls
    command ls -lah $argv
end
```